# Save as PDF with html2Canvas and jsPDF for php application works 1 time in 3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I would like to save an HTML page as PDF so I used html2canvas and jsPDF to do it.

The web application is in php and use Bootstrap 4 
On 1 side (1 table + 1 graph in chart.js) it works like a dream but on the other side, a view with multiple blocks it works 1 time in 3 and I would know why it's not stable...

I search on google and there's no CSS transformation that could make html2canvas bug, I think html2canvas could have some trouble to read the DOM on this side but need another point of view

Examples : 
1st side : [1 side that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRaQ6.jpg)

2nd side : [2nd side that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gokX.jpg)
[2nd side that doesn't work...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEFjb.jpg) 
Here's my code :

```
                    <div id="mad" class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <?php $this->load->view('block/rapport/mm_ma', $mad_data); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <?php $this->load->view('block/rapport/comments_section', array('block_id' => 'mad', 'comments' => $mad_data['comments'])); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="pdr" class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <?php $this->load->view('block/rapport/mm_ma', $pdr_data); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <?php $this->load->view('block/rapport/comments_section', array('block_id' => 'pdr', 'comments' => $pdr_data['comments'])); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </div>
```

My function to export as PDF :

```
        $(".loading-spinner-container").removeClass('d-flex').addClass('d-none'); //cache le loading spinner
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("body"), {scrollX: 0, scrollY: 0}).then(canvas => {
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            var pdf = new jsPDF("L");
            var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
            var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
            pdf.addImage(canvas, 'JPG', 0, 0, width, height);
            pdf.save("<?= ucfirst($this->uri->segment(2) . '/' . $this->uri->segment(3, '')) . "_" . date("Ymd") . ".pdf" ?>");
            show_content();
        });
    }
```

I hide the sidebar and the topbar because I noticed that it could make html2canvas to shift the image but now some cells comes out of their box and sometimes don't...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by setting the option of html2canvas 'foreignObjectRendering' = true